# Expected number of coin tosses until number of head exceeds number of tails by n or vice versa.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You can picture this as a game where each round, person A wins with "Heads", and person B wins with "Tails". They continue playing until one person has won $n$ more rounds than the other. What is the expected number of rounds played per game?

Let $X$ be the number of rounds plays.

If $n=1$, then clearly $E(X) = 1$.

If $n=2$, I think that $P(X=2) = 1/2, P(X=4) = 1/4, P(X=6) = 1/8$ and so on. And so $E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2k \;P(X=2k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} 2k = 4$

If $n=3$, I think that $P(X=3) = 1/4, P(X=5) = 3/16, P(X=7) = 9/64$, and $P(X=2k+1) = \frac{3^{k-1}}{4^k}$, and so $E(X) = 9$.

What is the answer is general?

Initially I thought it might be $n^2$, but for $n>3$, there's more cases to consider for which makes it a bit harder.

Comment: The pattern continues. I checked with this SageMath code: `sum(((matrix.identity(n) - matrix([[1 if i==0 and j==1 else 1/2 if abs(i-j)==1 else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]))^(-1))[0])` It uses the fundamental matrix of an absorbing Markov chain stuff.

Comment: Fascinating, the numbers in the first row of the fundamental matrix (which are the expectations of visits to the states before absorption) seem to be the even numbers except the first one is $n$ and when you "distribute" the first number to the rest and then one is left over, you get the odd numbers, which do sum to $n^2$.

Comment: Slightly generalising, if the match stops when either A is ahead by $a$ or B is ahead by $b$, and each player is equally likely to win each game independently of the other games, then the expected number of games required is $ab$, so if $a=b=n$ then this is $n^2$.   This is a consequence of $1+\frac12(a-1)(b+1)+\frac12(a+1)(b-1)=ab$

Comment: @ploosu2 thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @Henry Interesting. Can you think of an intuitive way to explain that, or an easier proof that just calculating explicitly as I tried to do?

Comment: You can turn this into $a+b$ simple simultaneous equations which are easily solved

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
11 & 20 & 18 & 16 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
10 & 20 & 18 & 16 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
9 & 18 & 18 & 16 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
8 & 16 & 16 & 16 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
7 & 14 & 14 & 14 & 14 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
6 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
5 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
4 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
3 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\end{array}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_t$ be the amount of wealth that person A has after $t$ rounds. This means $A_0=0$, and $A_{t+1}$ is either $A_{t}-1$ or $A_{t}+1$, independently of $A_0,A_1,\dots,A_{t-1}$.

I claim that the sequence $\{A_t^2-t\}_{t\ge 0}$ is a [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)), with respect to the filtration $\mathcal F_t=\sigma(A_1,\dots,A_t)$. This is proved by the following calculation:
$$
\begin{align}
E[A_{t+1}^2-t-1\mid A_1,\dots,A_{t}]
  &= E[A_{t+1}^2\mid A_1,\dots,A_t]-(t+1)
\\&= (1/2)(A_t+1)^2+(1/2)(A_t-1)^2-(t+1)
\\&= A_t^2-t.
\end{align}
$$
Now, let $T$ be the index of the first time where $A_T=+n$ or $A_T=-n$. Because $T$ has finite expectation, and because the increments of $A_t^2-t$ are bounded, the optimal stopping theorem implies that
$$
E[A_T^2-T]=E[A_0^2-0]=0.
$$
This implies that
$$
E[T]=E[A_T^2]=n^2.
$$
Note that $A_T=\pm n$ by definition of $T$, which is why $E[A_T^2]=n^2$.