# the expected number of coin tosses required to observe the first occurrence of k more heads than tails?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes

Assume we have a biased coin that lands heads with probability $p$ and tails with probability $1-p$. We toss this coin consecutively until we observe $k$ more heads than tails for the first time, at which point we stop tossing.

The questions of interest are as follows:

1. Upon stopping, if there are $h$ heads, then there must be $h-k$ tails. What is the number of possible configurations, denoted as $C(h, k)$? While I suspect a relationship with [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), I have yet to derive an exact formula.
2. What is the expected number of coin tosses, $E[n]$, required to reach this stopping condition? The precise definition of $E[n]$ is given by:
   $$E[n] = \sum_{h=k}^{\infty} (2h - k) C(h, k) p^{h} (1-p)^{h-k}$$
   I believe there may be an alternative, more efficient method for computing this, perhaps via a recurrence relation.

Comment: Why should it be finite?  Say $k=1$ and $p=.5$   Then note that, if the first toss is $T$ it should take twice as long.  Thus $E=\frac 12\times 1+\frac 12(1+2E)$ which has no finite solution.

Comment: @lulu no problem, then in this case the expected value is $+\infty$

Comment: Well, the same argument applies generally.

Comment: @lulu I think for $p > 0.5$, the expected value is finite, since when $p=1$, the expected value is $1$, I guess in final formula there is some scaling like $1/(p-0.5)$

Comment: The recursion I wrote down can easily be modified to handle the case of $p>.5$.  You get $E=\frac 1{2p-1}$.

Comment: Then for $p > 0.5$, for general k, $E = k / (2p-1)$. For $p \le 0.5$, $E = +\infty$.

Comment: Exactly.  $\quad $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Computing $C(h,k)$

Let
$$
S_n=\text{(# heads $-$ # tails) after $n$ flips}
$$
Note that the ordered pairs $(n,S_n)$ for $n\in \{0,1,\dots\}$ will trace out a path in the Euclidean plane, where each step is either $(+1,+1)$ or $(+1,-1)$. You want to count the number of such paths, with exactly $h+(h-k)=2h-k$ steps, with exactly $h$ instances of $(+1,+1)$ and $h-k$ instances of $(+1,-1)$, such that the walk hits the line $y=k$ for the first time at the very end.

The final step of such a walk must be an up step. If you delete this final up-step, then what remains is a walk which starts at $(0,0)$, and ends at $(2h-k-1,k-1)$, which always stays at or below the line $y=k-1$. Now, take this shortened path, and reverse both the $x$-axis and $y$-axis. The result is now a path with the same number of steps, still each $(+1,+1)$ or $(+1,-1)$, still from $(0,0)$ to $(2h-k-1,k-1)$, but now the walk stays at or above the line $y=0$. Applying the answer to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761344/the-number-of-of-dyck-paths-that-do-not-end-at-level-0/4761651#4761651), we conclude that the number of walks is $$C(h,k)=\binom{2h-k-1}{h-1}-\binom{2h-k-1}{h}$$
However, using this directly in your expression for expected value is pretty messy; there is a better way to compute the expectation.

#### Computing the expected number of flips

Let $q=1-p$. I will assume that $p>0.5$, initially. In this case, the expected number of flips is $k/(p-q)$, and there is an intuitive explanation.

For each $n\ge 1$, let $X_n=+1$ if the $n^\text{th}$ flip is heads, and $X_n=-1$ if it is tails. This means that $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$. Note that
$$
E[X_n]=p-q
$$

This means that the quantity $S_n$ increases by $p-q$, on average, with each flip. Therefore, the time it takes for $S_n$ to reach $+k$ should be $k/(p-q)$, on average. We can make this precise using Wald's equation.

Let $T$ be the number of flips it takes to each $+k$ for the first time. Using Wald's equation, we have
$$
E[S_T]=E[T]\cdot E[X_n]=E[T]\cdot (p-q)
$$
On the other hand, by definition of $T$, $S_T=+k$ always, so we conclude $E[S_T]=k$ and $E[T]=k/(p-q)$.

On the other hand, if $p\le 0.5$, you can prove that $E[T]=\infty$.

- First, suppose $p<0.5$. In this case, the law of large numbers implies $$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n/n= p-q<0,$$Let $T_k$ be the smallest $n$ such that $S_n=+k$. Note that $T_1,T_2-T_1,T_3-T_2,\dots $ all have the same distribution. If $E[T_1]<\infty$, this would mean each $E[T_k]=k\cdot E[T-1]$ is finite, so we would conclude that there is an infinite subsequence $S_{T_1},S_{T_2},\dots$ converging to $+\infty$, almost surely. This contradicts the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n/n$ is strictly negative.
- The case $p=1/2$ is the most subtle. Again, let $T_k$ be the time it takes to hit $+k$. If we suppose $E[T_1]$ is finite, then it would follow $E[T_k]=k\cdot E[T_1]$ grows linearly as a function of $k$. However, define $$\tilde T_k=\min\left\{n\,:\, |T_n|=k\right\}.$$ Note $\tilde T_k\le T_k$, so $E[\tilde T_k]\le E[T_k]=k\cdot E[T_1]$. We would conclude $E[\tilde T_k]$ grows at most linearly as a function of $k$. This a contradiction, since you can [prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756236/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-until-number-of-head-exceeds-number-of-tails-by-n/4756531#4756531) that $E[\tilde T_k]=k^2$.